# How to turn on VPN in Epic Browser

Tags: vpn, browser

I just upgraded Epic browser to `Version 79.0.3946.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

The VPN connection icon is gone.

I would expect to see an icon that looks like an extension cord plugging together to the right of the address bar.

I have search settings and googled for about a 1/2 hour trying to find the answer.

The epic official forum is not allowing new users to register so I am posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt have the icon either.

I clicked the three vertical dots at the extreme right of the page.

The dropdown menu gave me the option to click "More Tools"
Then choose Extensions and you'll open up a page with both Adblocker and Encrypted
Proxy showing. Both options are turned off so move the blue buttons to the right which then turns on both options.

Good to go !

Comment: As of 2022-07-30 this is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now an extension

You have open the Epic browser and open this page:

https://epicbrowser.com/webstore2/webstore/

Then select the `Encrypted Proxy VPN Service` extension.